Blockhash expired causing "program deploy" failed on mainnet
The program deployment requires sending around 90 transactions (based on the cli prompt). The same deployment works fine on devnet (very fast, a few seconds).
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 2 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 1 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 0 retries remaining
Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded


Tried private rpc
Tried --skip-fee-check
Tried --use-udp or --use-quic, the prompt is slightly different but still does not work
Tried the same version as main cluster (1.17.28), or upgrade it with solana-install update to 1.17.31, or directly install to 1.18.4. None works.

Any suggestions on how to avoid the error?

If you're using a private RPC, you should be able to land the transactions more easily using the --use-rpc flag, which was introduced in 1.18.12.
To go with that, there's also a --with-compute-unit-price flag that you can use to set a priority fee for your transactions, making the whole command something like:
solana program deploy --use-rpc --with-compute-unit-price 5000 path/to/your/program.so

